# Comparing Occurrence Of Data Within Two Groups

Tags: r, grouping, repeat, find-occurrences

I have a Data with User_Name and Group.

```
User_Name    Group
MustafE       A
fischeta      A
LosperS1      A
MustafE       B    
fischeta      B  
jose          B  
MustafE       c   
fischeta      c
```

I want to flag those customers which are not repeating groups .. Example - 'LosperS1' is in group A but not in group B , same way 'jose' is in group B but not in group C, so in a new column they will be marked as "No In group B/No In group C"

Any help will be appreciated ..

Comment: Try `df1 %>% distinct(User_Name) %>% pull(User_Name) %>% map_df(~ df1 %>% filter(User_Name == .x) %>% mutate(Flag = toString(setdiff(unique(df1$Group), unique(Group)))) %>% slice(1) %>% select(-Group)) %>% right_join(df1, "User_Name")`

Comment: Awwessome .... Exactly what I wanted .. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the output using `tidyverse`.  Get the `distinct` elements of 'User_Name' column, loop through those elements (`map`), `filter` the rows of the dataset based on the presence of looped elements in 'User_Name', `paste` the elements that are not found in the 'Group' column when compared with the filtered 'Group', subset the first row (`slice`) and `right_join` with the original dataset.  We used `map_df` to get the end output as a single data.frame instead of a `list` of `data.frame`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   distinct(User_Name) %>% 
   pull(User_Name) %>% 
   map_df(~ df1 %>%
              filter(User_Name == .x) %>%
              mutate(Flag = toString(setdiff(unique(df1$Group), 
                                             unique(Group)))) %>% 
              slice(1) %>%
              select(-Group)) %>% 
              right_join(df1, "User_Name")
```